# Oracle : does select from json_table keep order of rows exactly matching with order of json elements in array?

Tags: arrays, json, oracle, sorting

Good day.
The question almost the same as topic subject.
So, if I have a query:

```
select t.* from mytable m,
            json_table
            (m.json_col,'$.arr[*]'
             columns(...)
            ) t
      where m.id = 1
```

should I bother with order of rows?

TIA,
Andrew.

Comment: Small examples would suggest the "yes" answer - but there are other similar questions where small examples suggest "yes" but on bigger examples it turns out to be "no". Nothing in the documentation *guarantees* the order of generated values will preserve the array order (and, to the contrary, the syntax explicitly allows the generation of an ordinality column - presumably so that the order can be documented in the query). So, the answer is "how important is your task" and "what risks you are willing to accept".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many things to do with databases, there is a difference between the theoretical and the practical and the practical at large scales:

- In theory, a result set is an unordered set of rows *unless* you have specified an `ORDER BY` clause.
- In practice, for small data sets, the query will be handled by a single process and will generate rows in the order the rows are read from the data file and then processed; which means that it will read a row from `mytable` and then process the JSON data in order and produce the rows in the same order as the array.
- In practice at larger scales, the query may be handled by multiple processes on a parallel system (among other factors that may affect the order in which results are generated) where each process reads part of the data set and processes it and then the outputs are combined into a single result set. In this case, there is no guarantee which part of the parallel system will provide the next row and a consistent order cannot be guaranteed.

If you want to guarantee an order then use a `FOR ORDINALITY` column to capture the array order and then use an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT m.something,
       t.*
FROM   mytable m
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         m.json_col,
         '$.arr[*]'
         COLUMNS(
           idx   FOR ORDINALITY,
           value NUMBER PATH '$'
         )
       ) t
WHERE  m.id = 1
ORDER BY m.something, t.idx
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id        NUMBER,
  something VARCHAR2(10),
  json_col  CLOB CHECK(json_col IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO mytable(id, something, json_col)
SELECT 1, 'AAA', '{"arr":[3,2,1]}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'BBB', '{"arr":[17,2,42,9]}' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SOMETHING | IDX | VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | AAA | 1 | 3 |
> | AAA | 2 | 2 |
> | AAA | 3 | 1 |
> | BBB | 1 | 17 |
> | BBB | 2 | 2 |
> | BBB | 3 | 42 |
> | BBB | 4 | 9 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=309805264708c8bb4cc646706c364a4a)*
*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=20e9029ddefcf2062387868e85908beb)*